# load images using asyncimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tableview with custom cell on which there are two image view.

[image]

I have used asyncimageview for loading the images from url.  But the image is loading only on imageview1 not to imageview2. Following is the code I have used

```
            AsyncImageView *lImageView = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.image1.frame] autorelease];
            lImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
            lImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            lImageView.tag = 1;

            AsyncImageView *lImageView1 = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.image2.frame] autorelease];
            lImageView1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
            lImageView1.clipsToBounds = YES;
            lImageView1.tag = 2;
            [cell.image1 addSubview:lImageView];
             [cell.image2 addSubview:lImageView1];


    AsyncImageView *lImageView = (AsyncImageView *)[cell.image1 viewWithTag:1];
   [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:lImageView];
                    lImageView.imageURL =[NSURL URLWithString:pathimage1];

    AsyncImageView *lImageView1 = (AsyncImageView *)[cell.image2 viewWithTag:2];
   [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:lImageView1];
                    lImageView1.imageURL =[NSURL URLWithString:pathimage2];
```

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.